# VBA error: Why does my code keep jumping back lines?

Tags: vba, excel

I apologise for the code dump, but after two days of debugging, I think I'm starting to lose it, and I'm getting desperate. I have developed the code shown below

```
intColumnCount = wsStaff.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column  
intColumnLoop = 2  
intStaffCount = 0  
wsDisplay.Range("A2").EntireRow.UnMerge  
wsDisplay.Range("A2").EntireRow.Value = ""  
Do  
  intRowCount = wsStaff.Cells(Rows.Count, intColumnLoop).End(xlUp).Row  
  intRowLoop = 2  
  Do  
    If IsEmpty(wsStaff.Cells(intRowLoop, intColumnLoop)) And intRowLoop <> 2 Then  
      wsStaff.Range(wsStaff.Cells(intRowLoop, intColumnLoop).Address).Delete Shift:=xlUp  
      intRowCount = wsStaff.Cells(Rows.Count, intColumnLoop).End(xlUp).Row  
    Else  
      intStaffCount = intStaffCount + 1  
      If wsDisplay.Cells(1, intStaffCount + 2).Value <> wsStaff.Cells(intRowLoop, intColumnLoop).Value And wsDisplay.Cells(1, intStaffCount + 2).Value <> wsStaff.Cells(intRowLoop + 1, intColumnLoop).Value And wsDisplay.Cells(1, intStaffCount + 2).Value <> wsStaff.Cells(2, intColumnLoop + 1).Value And wsDisplay.Cells(1, intStaffCount + 2).Value <> "" Then  
        wsDisplay.Range(wsDisplay.Cells(1, intStaffCount + 2).Address).EntireColumn.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft  
        intRowCount = wsStaff.Cells(Rows.Count, intColumnLoop).End(xlUp).Row  
        intStaffCount = intStaffCount - 1  
      ElseIf wsDisplay.Cells(1, intStaffCount + 2).Value = wsStaff.Cells(intRowLoop + 1, intColumnLoop).Value Or wsDisplay.Cells(1, intStaffCount + 2).Value = wsStaff.Cells(2, intColumnLoop + 1).Value Or wsDisplay.Cells(1, intStaffCount + 2).Value = "" Then  
        wsDisplay.Range(wsDisplay.Cells(1, intStaffCount + 2).Address).EntireColumn.Insert Shift:=xlToRight  
        wsDisplay.Cells(1, intStaffCount + 2).Value = wsStaff.Cells(intRowLoop, intColumnLoop).Value  
        intRowLoop = intRowLoop + 1  
      Else  
        intRowLoop = intRowLoop + 1  
      End If  
      If wsDisplay.Cells(1, intStaffCount + 2).Value = wsDisplay.Cells(1, intStaffCount + 1).Value Then  
        wsDisplay.Range(wsDisplay.Cells(1, intStaffCount + 2).Address).EntireColumn.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft  
        intRowCount = wsStaff.Cells(Rows.Count, intColumnLoop).End(xlUp).Row  
        intStaffCount = intStaffCount - 1  
      End If  
      wsDisplay.Cells(1, intStaffCount + 2).Interior.Color = RGB(255 - (0.1 * (255 - intColourPalette(intColumnLoop Mod 6 + 1, 1))), 255 - (0.1 * (255 - intColourPalette(intColumnLoop Mod 6 + 1, 2))), 255 - (0.1 * (255 - intColourPalette(intColumnLoop Mod 6 + 1, 3))))  
    End If  
  Loop While Not intRowLoop > intRowCount  
  wsDisplay.Range(wsDisplay.Cells(2, 4 + intStaffCount - intRowCount).Address, wsDisplay.Cells(2, 2 + intStaffCount).Address).Merge  
  wsDisplay.Range(wsDisplay.Cells(2, 4 + intStaffCount - intRowCount).Address).Interior.Color = RGB(intColourPalette(intColumnLoop Mod 6 + 1, 1), intColourPalette(intColumnLoop Mod 6 + 1, 2), intColourPalette(intColumnLoop Mod 6 + 1, 3))  
  wsDisplay.Cells(2, 4 + intStaffCount - intRowCount).Value = wsStaff.Cells(1, intColumnLoop).Value  
  wsDisplay.Cells(2, 4 + intStaffCount - intRowCount).Font.Bold = True  
  wsDisplay.Cells(2, 4 + intStaffCount - intRowCount).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)  
  intColumnLoop = intColumnLoop + 1  
Loop While Not intColumnLoop > intColumnCount  
wsDisplay.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Orientation = -45  
wsDisplay.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.HorizontalAlignment = xlRight  
wsDisplay.Range(wsDisplay.Cells(1, 3), wsDisplay.Cells(2, intStaffCount + 2)).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous  
intDisplayRowLength = wsDisplay.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column  
intEraser = intStaffCount + 3  
wsDisplay.Range(wsDisplay.Cells(1, intEraser), wsDisplay.Cells(1, intDisplayRowLength)).EntireColumn.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft  
End Sub
```

So I have two issues, both involve the code jumping back lines and reperforming code. I figured this out by stepping through the code hundreds of times with almost all the code on breakpoints under different variable conditions.

The code frequently would jump back to the start whenever intRowCount was redefined, this error is not harmful to the output but it does dramatically increase computational time. I understand this may be built in to the Do loops and so is inconvenient but not the biggest issue.

The biggest issue is the second last line, after deleting all the unnecessary columns the code will jump back to the last end if statement, which is inside the nested do Loop. I have no idea why it is jumping back, on top of that it seems that the intRowCount, intRowLoop, intColumnCount and intColumnLoop variables change to allow repeat loops of the code.

The reason this is so catastrophic is because the intStaffCount doesn't change, meaning data is being added twice.

If anyone can provide any insight It would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: It is jumping to the position in the code that a new item was added and chooses to infinitely do so whenever it reaches the second last line.

Edit 2: It actually is reaching the End Sub line, it's just not ending

Edit 3: Solution found external to the code shown, events had to be disabled before the sub was called and re-enabled after

Comment: Have you been using the Locals Window and Immediate Window to help you debug?

Comment: No I haven't, not sure what that is but I'll look it up, Just been using break points and hovering over variables to find their values. I've only been using vba for excel for about two weeks.

Comment: Standard advice when running a loop which might delete rows or columns is to work backwards - start with the bottom-most row or right-most column. Otherwise you add complication by trying to keep track of which row/column you should currently be looking at. Also, `wsStaff.Range(wsStaff.Cells(intRowLoop, intColumnLoop).Address).Delete Shift:=xlUp` is the same as `wsStaff.Cells(intRowLoop, intColumnLoop).Delete Shift:=xlUp`

Comment: Sam, this is your lucky day.  Because they are amazing.  Go to view, Locals Window, and then step through your code. You won't need to research it, as its going to be self explanatory.  The immediate window is really nice for just typing in a variable and seeing the immediate value associated with it.  Research how to use the immediate window.

Comment: Could you confirm is this just a standard Sub in a normal module or is this an event handling procedure that's in a module tied to a Worksheet or Workbook?

Comment: it's a standard sub inside a module being called on the event of a worksheet change

Comment: I'm currently trying to rewrite the code for reading backwards but I seem to be limited when testing the line `wsDisplay.Cells(1, intStaffCount + 2).Value = wsStaff.Cells(2, intColumnLoop + 1).Value` as I think I'll have to find the length of the column previous.

Comment: Does the calling `Worksheet_Change` procedure disable events before calling this Sub? If not, then if the `Worksheet_Change` procedure relates to `wsStaff`or `wsDisplay`, you are very likely to be repeatedly triggering that event. Try pausing the execution of the program and looking at the call stack (via View > Call Stack)

Comment: Of Course! I'll check if that does it, gah can't believe I overlooked that

Comment: Works as intended now, thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem existed not in my module code but in the event code, by disabling events while the program was being called, the problem was resolved. Thank you to barrowc for the solution.